# Laravel 5.8: POST Route Does Not Seem To Be Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel 5.8 for my project and in this project, I have added this route:

```
Route::post('course_admin/{id}','CourseController@AcceptWalletCourse')->name('accept.walletCourse');
```

And here is the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('accept.walletCourse',['id'=>last(request()->segments())]) }}">
   @csrf

   Are you sure?

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Yes</button>
</form>
```

And at the Controller, I added this:

`dd($request);`

But I don't know why nothing appears as result. I mean the page just refreshes without showing any error or any `dd` result.

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to simplify everything:

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('accept.walletCourse',['id'=> 12]) }}">
   @csrf

   Are you sure?

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Yes</button>
</form>
```

In your controller:

```php
public function AcceptWalletCourse($id)
{
    dd($id); //should print 12
}
```

Once you are at this point, you can start adding validations, policies or dynamic parameters in your form (for instance `last(request()->segments())`) .

By proceeding step by step, you will quickly find where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `php artisan clear-compiled  composer dump-autoload php artisan optimize`